# Find Eigen values and eigen vectors

Tags: matrices

$\displaystyle F=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Expanding along $R_3$, I got the equation $(1-\lambda)(\lambda)(\lambda-2)=0$

Eigenvector corresponds to $\lambda=1$: $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Got stuck for $\lambda=2$.

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 2\\0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Cannot obtain the eigenvector $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I've cleaned up your MathJax code a bit. Note that you use ` \\\`  for a line break and only for a line break. If you want to use a command like `\begin{pmatrix}` then it's important that you only use one backslash, not two. Also: Put all the things which belong to a formula into one big equation box , e.g. `$ (1-\lambda)(\lambda - 2) = 0 $`

Comment: How do you get this characteristic polynomial, it isn't correct...

Comment: Note that $F$ is an upper triangular matrix. So your characteristic polynomial is merely $(X - 1)^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix is triangular, hence its eigenvalues are on the diagonal. In this case we have $\lambda=1$ with algebraic multiplicity of $3$.

For $\lambda=1$ we get $(F-\lambda I)v=0\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}0&1&2\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix}=0$ And we get $v_2=-2v_3$, thus the solution is of the form $\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\-2v_3\\v_3\end{pmatrix}=v_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+v_3\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$, hence the eigenspace corresponds to $\lambda=1$ is $\displaystyle \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

As we can see, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is $2$, so this matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: The matrix is obviously not diagonalizable: if it were, it would be the identity matrix (it has a unique eigenvalue).

Comment: I have not yet done this bit in eigen values. Shall check into this, thnx